# Azure App Service Mobile Apps - error "The site name for the code website is already taken"

Tags: azure, mobile-application, azure-web-app-service

I tried to create an Azure App service Mobile App following this Microsoft 
[App Service tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-ios-get-started-preview/#create-new-service)

but when I tried to set my Api App name, it didn't allow me to use dot character, stating that ["The site name for the code website is already taken"](http://screencast.com/t/hkmopYfkY) although it must be quite unique. If I remove dot from the Api App name - it is accepted as unique. The interesing part is that name suggested (when I start to create this App is "Microsoft.Mobile" which suggest that dot is an acceptable character...)

Of course, I can set it a name without dot, but would prefer to use it for organizational reasons.
Any ideas what is the problem here, why dot is not accepted?